# How to check if a number is 0.0 ie floating point zero in Python3?

Tags: floating-point, python-3.6, equality, zero

I have a list of items of different *types*, say

`arr = [False, 0, 78, 'string', 0.0, True, None, [], ()]`

Now I need a function to check if `0.0` i.e. `float(0)` exists in the array, and return its index.
How do I do it?

Note that it should ignore others values like `False`, `0`, `None`, etc.

**Edit:**
I also tried 
`if n is 0.0` and `if n is float(0)` and failed. So bonus question, why does this not work?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What isn't working?

Comment: @Mozahler I have tried: `if n is 0.0:` and `if n is float(0):`. And obviously `if n == 0.0` or `if not n` didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
arr = [False, 0, 78, 'string', 0.0, True, None, [], ()]
for idx, item in enumerate(arr):
    if isinstance(item, float) and item == 0.0:
        print(idx)
```